# Change IE homepage - overwrite group policy script

Tags: explorer, group-policy

I'm in IT at my workplace but I can't change any Group Policy settings.

I want my PC to run this script every time it boots up, effectively overwriting the IE homepage which is set by our group policy. Normally it is directed to my company's homepage which takes too long to load, plus it's not useful for me.

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /V "Start Page" /D "http://www.google.com.au" /F
```

This needs to run at every boot as the GP will overwrite that registry key. What is the best way to implement this each time the PC boots?

If there is an alternative script/command, I'll use that.